# Doctrine2, Check entity in an Arraycollection with queryBuilder

Tags: doctrine-orm, arraycollection, query-builder

I have just a simple question about the query builder but I haven't find any answers...

I make a filter for product's list and I want to check if my selected attributes are in the arrayCollection "attributes" of my Items ( items of products ).

Here's my Attributes arrayCollection in Item entity :

```
/**
*
* @var ArrayCollection
*
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Attribute", inversedBy="items")
* @ORM\JoinTable(name="catalog_items_x_attributes", joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id")}, inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="attribute_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
*/ 
private $attributes;
```

Here's my function in ProductRepository ( Products had 1-x items ) :

```
public function listWithFilters($idCat, $filt)
{      
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $cat = $em->getRepository('WebformanceCatalogBundle:Category')
     ->findById($idCat);<br />
    $right = $cat[0]->getRight();
    $left = $cat[0]->getLeft();
    $query = $qb
            ->select('p')
            ->from('Webformance\CatalogBundle\Entity\Product', 'p')
            ->leftJoin('Webformance\CatalogBundle\Entity\Item', 'i', 'WITH', 'i.product = p.id' )
            ->leftJoin('Webformance\CatalogBundle\Entity\Category', 'c', 'WITH', 'p.category = c.id')
            ->where('c.right <= :right')
            ->andWhere('c.left >= :left')
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->between('i.salePrice', ':minPrice', ':maxPrice'))
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->between('i.weight', ':minWeight', ':maxWeight'))
            ->setParameters(array('right' => $right,
                                    'left' => $left,
                                    'minPrice' => $filt['price-min'],
                                    'maxPrice' => $filt['price-max'], 
                                    'minWeight' => $filt['weight-min'],
                                    'maxWeight' => $filt['weight-max']
                ));
            if (!empty($filt['manufacturer'])) {
               $query
                ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('p.manufacturer', ':manufacturers'))
                ->setParameter('manufacturers', $filt['manufacturer']);
            }

/***** problem on this part ******/
// I have already try without the "getRepository" just with the ID.
                if (!empty($filt['att'])) {
                    foreach($filt['att'] as $attId) {
                        $attribute = $em->getRepository('WebformanceCatalogBundle:Attribute')
                         ->findById($attId);
                        $query
                            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in(':attributes', 'i.attributes'))
                            ->setParameter('attributes', $attribute[0]);
                    }
                }
/********************************/
        $result = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
        return $result;
    }
```

So, I've an error like :

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 406: Error: Expected Literal, got 'i'
```

But i don't know if I use the good way to find that I want.